# Where is dust-full-0.3.0.min.js

Tags: dust.js

I have just started looking at linkedin `dustjs` framework, it's a really cool library. 
My question may sound silly, but I cant find the `dust-full-0.3.0.min.js` file to include in my page!

I would be thankful if anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

For the main dustjs project, you can can find the dust-full-0.3.0-min.js in the dist folder of the project when you clone it from GitHub.

https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs/tree/master/dist

For the LinkedIn fork of dustjs, you can find dust-full-1.1.1.js in its dist folder.

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/dist

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are looking for that version. You can find the 1.1.1 (not finished) version here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/dist

I you want the minified version, you have to minify it. You will find a make task in the make file called: "min". So if you execute make min, you will get the minified version inside dist folder.

older versions:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tags